# XENU Link Sleuth - How to skip Images?

Tags: html, google-maps, xenu

My website is a static html photo gallery which has more than 100,000 html pages with no database, just simply html (old website, not a adult site)

I used to create sitemap and find broken links using Xenu application and I did skipped images (*.jpg) when creating a sitemap before but now (after some 4 years) its not working or I forget what I added in exclude options.

[image: Xenu Screenshot]

I used below formats to exclude/skip images to add in generating list/checking.

```
*.jpg*
*jpg*
*.jpeg*
*jpeg*
```

But its not working.

I really need to skip images because if there is 100k html pages, there is 100k HQ photos with 100k thumbnails :( and all this will make bigger sitemap and I don't want my direct photo links to index in search engine.

Please help. Any possible ways to skip "image/jpeg" ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: No One Knows ? :/

Comment: I've never seen a regular expression work with this program. The only option you have is to exclude files starting with a particular string. For example: if you wanted to exclude all files in the images directory, you would add `http://domain.tld/images/` to the "Do not check any URLs beginning with this" section.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I am sure I used Xenu for sitemap before and never used folder path or any urls to filter. I am confused now. I just checked my old sitemap and it does not have image links, it has more than 100k links and this cant be generated by other free apps out there. Anyway, I am checking for php script to do the job. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar requirement, and it turns out that Xenu have a "wildcard edition" that works with regex.  It is available on their website.

Comment: > This is available but not in the general version. Download it here, however, this may not always be the latest version. Just enter something with a "*" instead of an URL, e.g. "*print*" to exclude an "easy print" version of a web page. Note that only "*" is supported; "?" is not, nor are "regular expressions" (because an average user won't understand the concept). Also, don't forget the "*" at the beginning and the end of the URL, unless you want the expression to be a prefix or a suffix.

https://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html#:~:text=This%20is%20available,or%20a%20suffix.